# Backing up connman settings on linux

Tags: linux, connman

I am tasked to do backup and restore for networking settings on linux which uses ConnMan. Is it possible for me to do so by copying settings inside `/var/lib/connman` and place them in the same folder when doing restore?

If not, any suggestion that I can use instead? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have emailed Jukka Rissanen, the person who works behind ConnMan. He replied this;

> Yes, you can backup /var/lib/connman and /var/lib/connman-vpn
> directories and restore them to same places to get the settings back.
>
> Note that if you restore to different machine than what the backup is
> from, some settings might not be available because network interface mac
> address is part of the path name of the settings file.
>
> Cheers,
> Jukka

Hope this helps anyone who is looking for the answer in the future.